# Change "Other email addresses" to "User name" in office 365

Tags: office365

I have 2 email addresses and want to change
-"Primary email address" to "Other email addresses" 
-"Other email addresses" to "User name" 
in office 365, can I do that?

One solution is to delete the account and start from the scratch, but I want to to have all history left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it, go to Office 365 admin center > USERS > Active users. Click EDIT on the right to change users’ user names. After that the primary email addresses will be changed as well and the old addresses will become aliases. Emails sent to the aliases can still be received.

The change of the user names and email addresses won’t affect the existing emails and calendar appointments.